# Typescript and React outputting require

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to get Typescript and React working together in MVC Core

The problem is the requirement for the following lines in my .tsx file:

```
import React = require('react');
import ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
```

These lines pass through both compilers becoming the following in the JS for browser processing:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
```

Obviously, the browser cannot run these lines, because "require" is not a function in the browser

And yes, I can verify that both Typescript and React have processed the file.

Elsewhere on the site, it is suggested to use a global import, however this is a bad idea (it even says so in that post), I could also fix this by creating an empty function called "require", but that would also be bad practice

That this situation has arisen at all I find surprising, I thought the whole point of TypeScript was to take better code that the browser doesn't understand and transform it into equivalent code that it would. Thus, that TypeScript has allowed these lines to just pass through is baffling to me.

I have tried using the module directive in tsconfig.json to produce the required output, however there doesn't seem to be a browser compatible option

Is there a way to get React's babel compiler to eat the require functions? Has Typescript left them in because it expects React to do something with them?

EDIT: My question is different from the one suggested as a duplicate because it asks about module() and not import.

Though I suspect the answers to the 2 questions may be the same, suggestions on the accepted answer such as "just us a reference" don't work and although use of an external module loader should solve the issue, it's a broken solution

require() is not a part of browser based JS, therefore I don't want TypeScript to output it at all

EDIT2: Since more details of my setup have been requested, here you go:
The structure of my wwwroot/js directory is as so:

```
/def
..react.d.ts
..react-dom.d.ts
tsconfig.json
source .tsx and compiled .js files
```

Note that the d.ts files are copypasta from the repositories. There doesn't seem to be a way to load them in "properly" without adding ridiculous dependencies to the project such as node. NuGet modules that seem to do this in regular mvc have no functionality in mvc core

I've also tried moving the d.ts files to be in the same folder as everything else, this has no effect

tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true, //Doesn't do anything? Build required to compile
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5", //Is this the ES version I'm supposed to be typing in or the ES version to compile to? Irrelevant, changing this does nothing
    "jsx": "react" //Using "preserve" outputs a jsx file to go through the React Babel compiler, does not solve issue
    //"module": Irrelevant, a "don't worry I've got them covered" flag option doesn't exist, no options are suitable for browser use
    //"noResolve": Irrelevant, does nothing
  },
  //"files":[] Explicitly including the d.ts files here doesn't seem to do anything, does not allow me to remove import lines
  "exclude": [ //Have tried removing this, doing so has no effect, does not allow me to remove import lines
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

Since I'm using Visual Studio everything compiles on build, I assume it's using tsc.exe under the hood

As for React... I have the following listed in the dependencies section of project.json

```
"React.AspNet": "2.5.0",
"React.Core": "3.0.0-rc1"
```

In startup.cs I have the following in ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddJsEngineSwitcher(
    options=>options.DefaultEngineName = V8JsEngine.EngineName
).AddV8();
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddReact();
```

...and the following in configure

```
app.UseReact(config => {});
```

For development purposes I have the following in my _Layout.cshtml

```
<environment names="Development">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.2/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.2/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
</environment>
```

This is a learning project so it won't go to production mode, but if it did I would self-host the react source code and put it through the default bundler for bundling and minification. I don't believe that the positives of using a cdn outweigh the risks

I have tried using /// references, they seem to be a deprecated feature and in this case they don't do anything

I have tried using the following syntax to import react, but this also leads to different non-browser compatible code being output

```
import React = __React;
import ReactDOM = __React.__DOM;
```

It's important to note that both TypeScript and React work completely under these conditions on their own, no node dependency, no silly packing thing. It is only the TypeScript module system that insists on outputting things I don't need

Comment: Usually, a bundler like Browserify or Webpack solves this by concatenating all the source files that you need and removing the `require` calls. Are you using one of those?

Comment: I am not, normally I would consider those tools as redundant because Visual Studio has it's own.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If I use \`module("somelib")\` in typescript, it can't be running in browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538099/if-i-use-modulesomelib-in-typescript-it-cant-be-running-in-browser)

Comment: It might be helpful if you could post your configuration files and describe how you're compiling your JS, if the other question isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Very well, all the details have been added to the original post. It would be super-nice if TypeScript had a way of informing a file of it's dependencies without it assuming that it needs to be talking to client-side module systems that not everyone wants to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right so... after much much researching, my conclusion is that MVC Core, TypeScript and React shouldn't all go together just yet.

A lot of documentation and discussions hint at some sort of implicit referencing that's possible, and that seems to be the preferred way forwards when your project doesn't warrant a client-side module system, however... this feature doesn't seem to work with non-Typescript modules, or if it does it's so obscure and badly documented that I can't figure it out

....this could be one of those things where it's so obvious to everyone else that nobody bothers discussing it, if it is please let me know how stupid I am

The bottom line seems to be that if you want to use TypeScript's module system, you're supposed to have a browser-side module system that it can talk to.

I've looked over all of these and put a lot of work into understanding which is the best one for React and .Net

React places some extra constraints on this because you want to be using it's Server Side Rendering feature... like, you seriously want to be using that it's the best thing about React, so you need a module system that also plays nicely with it.

I've concluded that RequireJS is probably the right way to go for a number of reasons, for the client it's just 1 lightweight JS file, which compares nicely to the gargantuan JS behemoths of it's competitors, and it's own server side components have a .net version which should lead to an easier time making them work with React's server side stuff

....unfortunately RequireJS's server side components have a dependency on the old MVC for .Net Framework, so you can't use them in MVC Core yet, for now it's a dead end

Honestly, coming from a decade and a half of Javascript programming, I find this assumption on TypeScript's part that everyone is using a heavy client-side module system to be more than a little scary

I think it's important to remember that no matter what scripting you do for the browser, it all either runs in, or compiles back to, Javascript. This means that nothing you can bring in can possibly be more powerful than Javascript on it's own.

You use these things because they're quicker to code with, easier to test, show up errors at design time etc etc, i.e. they make life much easier for you and your team, but just like a box of pills, every single one of them has side effects and if you use too many they build up and cause problems

These module systems all look like great tools in the right projects, just like every "pill" in the "box" mentioned above, but I don't think they should be nearly as ubiquitous as TypeScript seems to assume they are

If you go for a small client stack that closely fits the needs of your project, and correctly segregate your JS into a global bundle, and a set of view-specific bundles your application can grow very large without encountering any of the issues that you want a heavy module system to solve

If you ever find yourself thinking you need such a thing, I would take the time to go back over your tech stack and really work out what each piece is doing for you and whether it's worth the cost to have it there, cutting that stack down is in many cases going to be a much better way to keep it stable than adding yet another framework to it

You've got to ask yourself what problems each tool is solving for you, whether it's successful in doing so, and if there's a better way... particularly one provided by another tool on your stack, a solution requiring no additional tools at all, or a solution provided by removing the tool that causes the issue as a side effect

I've seen a lot of people talking about these module loaders as a way to avoid clashes caused by adding things to the global namespace, and I'm sorry but moving all of those names to a module list so that they can clash there instead really doesn't solve anything

That in mind... webpack.... I think I jumped too early on the node dependency here, on taking a closer look I think it just uses node to compile things at design time, which is fine, as long as it doesn't want node on my production server we're cool but... all webpack is doing is taking your require lines and using them to inline other scripts, that's not what these lines are meant to be used for and using them in this way defeats the object of using them in the first place

All it seems to do is take the modules and dump them back into the global namespace where you didn't want them in the first place, furthermore if you're taking my advice above and making a global bundle, and one for each view that needs it's own tooling you're going to run into problems doing things the webpack way.... again, please correct me if I've misjudged this one

Well, that's the best answer that I can come up with for now, really hoping some people will show up and discuss it with me because it feels like I'm missing the point in a few places

For now I'm going to look into a bunch of React specific things and then maybe I'll see if I can get this stack working in MVC for Framework and see what changes

And if someone can come up with a better answer or a proper solution becomes available in a few months after the components have been patched a bit more then I'll move the green tick over

Answer (score -1):

> Obviously, the browser cannot run these lines, because "require" is not a function in the browser

Indeed. What tutorial are you following? You definitely need a *module bundler* in addition to TypeScript compilation e.g. here is a quickstart on webpack : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html

Comment: I'm not following a tutorial per say, all of them are incomplete and out of date and none of them deal with mvc core particularly well, so I've been going back and forth, picking out the bits that are still relevant and figuring out everything else on my own

Comment: ...as for webpack, let me get this straight, I have TypeScript which works perfectly fine under .net on it's own, but if I want to use it with any other JS modules, including ones that also work perfectly fine on their own, I have to add a dependency on node.js to my project along with a 4th javascript compiler which does exactly the same thing as the default bundler just because Typescript insists on, in just this one instance, outputting lines that break the browser completely unnecessarily?

Comment: ...That's madness, it's total lunacy that doing all that and adding so much to the project is the right solution to this problem, and I refuse to be a part of it. I don't need TypeScript to output those lines, I have React's stuff where the whole site can see it already and I just need TypeScript to be aware of it, nothing more. I honestly feel that doing all that would be even less good practice than just putting a dummy require function in a JS file somewhere, so if that's this is the best the community can come up with then I will just have to find a better solution on my own

Comment: ...and if I can't do it then I'll just have to leave TypeScript behind, which would be a shame because aside from this it's a fantastic tool, but it isn't worth adding node.js and a duplicate bundler to a project for, especially not for such  a stupid reason